# How to Set Focus After Filled text box with Jquery AutoComplete?

Tags: jquery, html

I Think it is very easy, if I type on that text box or copy paste the below code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#textbox1").bind("input",function(){
           $("#textbox2").focus();
       });
    });
</script>
```

My Problem is, I have used Jquery Ui Plugin on the textbox. So, It does not work on it.

The All I need is After Auto Complete finish, focus will run. But right now, auto complete does not focus its textbox.

can anyone help me to fix this?

this the code 
https://jsfiddle.net/o25n6017/

But textbox 1 is autocomplate

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give demo with jsfiddle?

Comment: @Sadikhasan I have give demo on jsfiddle, but still cant create the autocomplate on text box1 on JSfidle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you want focus on `textbox2` after focusout from `textbox1` as per I understand.

```
$( "#TEXT_BOX1" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
      select: function ()
      {
           $("#TEXT_BOX2").focus();  
      }
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o25n6017/2/)**

Comment: I have try but not change anything?

Comment: `not change anything` means what ? Have you checked demo ?

Comment: Ya, I have see the Demo. I have type on checkbox 1 or copy and the focus still not change to textbox 2. or can you explain me what "focusout" for

Comment: I cant understand `checkbox 1 or copy and the focus` what you mean by this?

Comment: patient, i will explain the problem. text box 1 is auto complate. And What I Need is after Auto Complate have Finished (Finish mean, user click the suggest filled the textbox 1) the Cursor automatic focus on text box2.

Comment: O hope you understand.

Comment: I have search Event from Afternoon. it turns out only take focus inside the autocomplate. very Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <script>
  $(function() {

    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];

    $( "#TEXT_BOX1" ).autocomplete({
      // event ===  Autocomplete finished
      close: function(){
        $("#TEXT_BOX2").focus();
      },
      source: availableTags
    });
  });

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">

  <label for="tags">TEXT_BOX1: </label>
  <input id="TEXT_BOX1">

  <br><br><br>

   <label for="tags">TEXT_BOX2: </label>
  <input id="TEXT_BOX2">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

example on http://plnkr.co/edit/GgWFAckqbA1MaOeM1Dfy?p=preview